# How to execute a command that requires root permission without sudo?

Tags: sudo, root

I'm trying to execute `traceroute -d` being authenticated as a "standard" user with `sudo` privileges. However if I run  `sudo traceroute -d` it will be execute by the `root` user so I'm wondering how can I execute it as the standard user. 
 I've tried several ways to make the user basically a super user (aka root) but without success.

The only thing that worked was to change the uid and group id to 0 on /etc/passwd but that changes the user "identity" to "root". E.g. if I run whoami I get "root" instead the "standard" user name.

The reason why i need this is that I have some networking routing based on the --uid-owner and now I'm trying to debug it but it doesn't make sense to run with sudo b/c it would be execute as "root" user which has other routings.

Comment: What about `tracepath`? `tracepath` doesn't need `root`.

Comment: It's also possibile that traceroute only needs some [capability](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities). But I have never really understood the capabilities system.

Comment: If you're having problems editing sudoers doesn't work, then you should fix that problem first, rather than trying to find a workaround. sudoers can be fixed pretty easily.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can make the standard user work like a root user except its identity (.e.g username is myuser not root) even temporary

Comment: With a reasonably recent Linux kernel, you could make a [namespace](http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/) with its own network setup and where the user is root.

Answer (score 5):

`traceroute` need not run as `root`; it just needs the capability `CAP_NET_ADMIN`. Thus you can set this as file capability for the file and then `traceroute` will always have this capability (for all users, though), if your kernel supports file capabilities and no Linux Security Module (SELinux, AppArmor) is blocking it:

```
setcap CAP_NET_ADMIN+ep /usr/sbin/traceroute
```

While `traceroute` is running you can see its capabilities with `pscap`. This does not affect the UID/EUID of the process.

I don't know how to do that but AFAIK it is possible, too, to use AppArmor (and probably SELinux) to run a process with certain capabilities. The main task is, of course, to limit the available capabilities.