# How to allow traceroute to run as root on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I'm trying to programatically call traceroute on Ubuntu but i'm getting blocked when trying to use the -I or -T flags for ICMP/TCP packets.

Accroding to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172329/how-to-execute-a-command-that-requires-root-permission-without-sudo) I can use the terminal command `setcap CAP_NET_ADMIN+ep /usr/sbin/traceroute` to give traceroute the access it needs, but it's not working. The output is:

```
Failed to set capabilities on file `/usr/sbin/traceroute' (Invalid argument)
The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the file 
is not a regular (non-symlink) file
```

How can I give sudo permission to an app?

Comment: `setcap CAP_NET_ADMIN+ep "$(readlink -f /usr/sbin/traceroute)"`

Comment: Thanks that worked great!, also in addition to`CAP_NET_ADMIN` I needed `CAP_NET_RAW` and ran the permission against `tcptraceroute` in the sbin folder.