# change volume name without sudo / root

Tags: udev, usb-drive

I have a python program that should automatically change the disc volume names / labels for newly inserted usb mass storage devices - it just uses a system call like `fatlabel /dev/sdc1 MyNewLabel`
details in
https://github.com/s-light/usbstick_masscopy/blob/master/usbstick.py

currently i getting an `open: Permission denied` error. ok - for normal usage that is fine - if i want to change the disc-label i have to use root-privileges.

but i don't like to run my python script with sudo. so is there an other solution to this?
i think it could work in some way if i can create an udev rule that adds these newly attached usb-mass-storage devices to a special group or user that is allowed to change the labeling?!
could this work?

edit: i have found [how to execute a command without sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172329/how-to-execute-a-command-that-requires-root-permission-without-sudo) that points to the [capability system](https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities)
there the nearest i have found is 'CAP_SYS_ADMIN'
i have tested this [with this script](https://github.com/s-light/usbstick_masscopy/blob/master/permission_test.py) but i did not get it to work. (iam getting the permission denied errors..)

for my mounting and un-mounting i have found the [pmount and pumount](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Using_pmount) option - this works fine. something similar as replacement for `fatlabel` would be my favorite - but till now i did not find something.

i hope you have some advice / tips for me
sunny greetings stefan

Comment: `adduser <user> disk` or to the group which has write permission to device.

Comment: what permission has the 'disk' group? normal file read/write permission is working fine. have you some extended information on this?

Comment: The disk group has permission to write to all block devices, so it's probably something you don't really want: it lets you break your whole system and bypass filesystem permissions.

Comment: I'd recommend a udev rule that chowns the block device (specifically the USB stick — matching on the vendor ID, product ID, serial number, or similar) to your user or to a group which you are a member of (that isn't disk!), which should allow you to change the partition label without root.